# How to unfold Mate Menu on hover (hot corner)

Tags: gui, mate, ubuntu-mate

One feature I like in Gnome desktop is the hot corner. it's easy to search for applications using the hot corner and also to look at open windows.

Mate menu (could be added using right click --> add to panel) is written in Python and it's a fork from Mint menu. it shows you list of applications categories and you can use it to search for softwares.

Is it possible to trigger unfold on hover in this menu so it would act like Gnome hot corner feature? That will save many clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be done by editing the file:

```
/usr/lib/mate-menu/mate-menu.py
```

then adding one line:

```
        self.toggleMenu()      # added by me
```

for me it was lines 547-549, watch out for indentions, 8 empty spaces before the third line, it should look like that:

```
    def enter_notify(self, applet, event):
        self.do_image(self.buttonIcon, True)
        self.toggleMenu()      # added by me
```

now kill the toolbar and it will start again with hot corner support.

```
killall mate-panel
```

[image]
enjoy

Thanks for Akuli from #mate channel at freenode.net for providing the answer

Comment: This is excellent! But it seems that it's only an option if you **Enable Advanced Menu** in MATE Tweak, right?

Comment: No, I did not need that.

Comment: ah OK - for me it only works if I enable advanced menu :)